# Reducing the number of table columns

Tags: database, sqlite, normalization

I'm trying to turn a huge spreadsheet of data into a database to make data analysis easier, but I'm running into problems with too many columns.  I've tried my best to learn about normalization, but I'm having a hard time applying it to this use case.

### Scenario

We are performing N *independent* measurements on rectangular blocks.  Measurements include:

- Length (or Measurement 0)
- Width (or Measurement 1)
- Height (or Measurement 2)
- Mass (or Measurement 3)
- Color (or Measurement 4)
- ...
- Measurement N

There are over 7000 measurements (complicated blocks)!  The measurements have limits.  If a block fails one or more measurements, all measurements are repeated to verify.  If it fails again, the block is deemed a failure.

The blocks are serialized and there are thousands of them.

### Data Source

A huge spreadsheet (table).  The fields are: Block Number, Length, Width, Height, Mass, Color, ..., Measurement N.  Each row represents one test run or execution of all measurements.  Since we have a retest policy, there may be multiple rows with results from the same block.

### Help!

This source table seems like an intuitive format, but doesn't seem like the best format for a database.  At first I tried to put it in an SQLite database and ran into the 2000 column limit.  Yes I could recompile SQLite with more columns or use another database engine, but this sounds like more of a database design issue.  Do you have a better design idea?

P.S. Sorry so long, but thanks for reading!

Comment: Are all of the measured values the same data type? That is, are all the measured values integers, or all floats, or all decimal?

Comment: Most measurements are floats, but some are text, like color.  If there was a significant benefit, I suppose I could split measurements into groups base on their value format.  In this post processing application maximum performance isn't as critical as accessibility.

Comment: Do you always make 7000 measurements at a time, or do you stop short sometimes?

Comment: Some we stop short.  Depending on the measurement, some failures can halt the entire test run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a `MeasurementType` table to hold the names of all measurements and any other information you may want to store about measurements.

Then you would have a `Measurement` table referencing both the `MeasurementType` and the "original" table that your spreadsheet is (i.e. the table left with the `Block Number` column):

```
CREATE TABLE MeasurementType (
    MeasurementTypeId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    MeasurementType TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE OriginalTable (
    OriginalTableId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    BlockNumber INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE Measurement (
    MeasurementTypeId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    OriginalTableId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    MeasurementValue,
    PRIMARY KEY (MeasurementTypeId, OriginalTableId),
    FOREIGN KEY (MeasurementTypeId) REFERENCES MeasurementType (MeasurementTypeId),
    FOREIGN KEY (OriginalTableId) REFERENCES OriginalTable (OriginalTableId));
```

Comment: This seems like the best option so far.  I implemented it.  Queries seem a little less intuitive than the many-column table option, but that just might be me.  Now I need to find a bit more efficient way to fill this `Measurement` table.  I'm filling the table using Python using two `for`loops, one for the rows and one for the columns of the original table, which doesn't scale well with thousands of blocks :)